# Change color JButton when on click and reset after not clicking

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, mouselistener, changelistener

I am writing a Java application that have buttons in it. I would like to know how could i change the color of jbutton when mouse is clicked on it and when mouse released the jbutton is backed to its default color. I have tried using MouseActionListener and ChangeListener but none of them works.

Thank you for your help

Comment: i looking for just the direction to solve the problem. So I think the code needn't to be posted

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you need to attach a ChangeListener to the buttons model. When a stateChanged event is raised, you need to check the current state of the model and make the changes you need as required...

```
final JButton btn = ....
bnt.getModel().addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent evt) {
        ButtonModel model =evt.getSource();
        // Check for the model state you want...
    }
});
```

Comment: if use stateChange Listener that will disable the ActionListener i register to the jbutton. I have tried that. thank you for you reply ...

Comment: Why should it disable the ActionListener?

Comment: so you are saying it won't effect the actionListener right ... I will give it another go and let you know .. thank you

Comment: My pcs running hard at the moment so I can't test it, but I can't see why it should, so long as your not actually changing the state of the model